# Compare numbers and remove numbers from a text file using C#

Tags: c#

I have created a text file with some random float numbers ranging from 743.6 to 1500.4.
 I am figuring out a way to read the text file (which i have did) and include a number range: lets say( 743.6 <= x <= 800) and remove the numbers which are outside the range and eventually store the final values in a text file.

I have managed to write some codes to read the text file so that when i compile it shows the numbers in the text file. Now i do not know how to progress further . Here is my code, which is able to run compile. This code now ables to read the textfile.

743.6

742.8

744.7

743.2

1000

1768.6

1750

1767

1780

1500

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadTextFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string filePath = "C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\Data\\TextFile.txt"; // File Direcotry

             List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

             foreach (string line in lines)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(line);
             }
             Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take a look at [ask] and try to make it a little clearer what you are struggling with exactly. A [mcve] of your best approach would also be very helpful. Also, please include your sample input file.

Comment: I have added my codes, please take a look.

Comment: How does the content of the file look? And how large is it?

Comment: Do you have the option to switch to some other format than plain text? Like XML or JSON?

Comment: I have added how the text file looks with the float numbers. Its a small text file. I am an novice in c # by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read all the lines and replace all values between your min and max value with an empty string:

```
float min = 800.5F, max = 850.5F;
float currentValue;

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(usersPath);
var separator = ';'; // Change this according to which separator you're using between your values (if any)

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    foreach (string word in line.Trim().Split(separator))
    {
        if (float.TryParse(word.Trim(), out currentValue))
        {
            if (currentValue < min || currentValue > max)
            {
                line.Replace(word, "");
            }
        }
    }
}
File.WriteAllLines(usersPath, lines);
```

Comment: 1. You are assuming there is only 1 number per line. I don't read that in question. 2. you cannot just cast a string to a float number like that. 3. _Do not trust user input_! What if one line says "GOTCHA!!!!11!!" ?

Comment: @Fildor Thanks, I improved my answer

Comment: Depending on how much number OP need to process, it might be worth it to put a placeholder float variable outside the loop, and use it to store the converted word before comparing it against min and max, instead of doing the conversion twice for each word.

Comment: I would argue we do not know enough to actually answer the question without making some kind of assumption that may or may not hold but void the answer.

Comment: @Fildor The question got more info now, which makes it possible to answer imo. Makes some of the improvements your suggested obsolete, but I will still keep them because they're good for other people who will find this answer

Comment: There is an error in line 6 separator saying Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'.

Comment: @user11612402 I edited my answer. Use `';'` instead of `";"`, so the variable will be a `char`, not a `string`

Comment: where exactly do i add those codes in my program sir? I gotto comment out some codes too like the string list

Comment: @user11612402 right after you declare `filePath`. Rename it to `usersPath` tho. Does it not work?

Comment: Nope it does not, it only shows the original numbers which was in the text file. it did not filter out which ever outside the range

Comment: @user11612402 I edited my answer 10 minutes ago, did you use the updated code? Former code had a mistake

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the data was not filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

This will read the file into memory, parse it, filter it and than overwrite the existing file with the new data.

```
File.WriteAllLines(filePath,
    File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
      .Select(x => double.Parse(x))
      .Where(x => x >= 800.5 && x <= 850.5)
      .Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for helping, May i know at which part of my code should i add that in?

Comment: @Kiwi Put it in your main method

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution w/ basic error detection and some robustness thanks to the use of regular expressions.
As a foreword: Using regular expressions can be quite expensive and they are **not** always the way to go.

In this case I think they're okay, because you're handling user-generated input (possibly). 
Regular expressions can be optimised by pre-compiling them!

```
/*
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
*/


void ReadFile(string filePath) {
    var fileInfo = default(FileInfo);
    var separator = @"[;\s:,]"; // This is a simple RegEx, can be done otherwise. This allows for a little more robustness IMO

    // VERY rudimentary error detection
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath), "The path to the file must not be null or empty!");

    try {
        fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    } catch {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(filePath), "A valid path must be given!");
    }

    if (!fileInfo.Exists) {
        throw new IOException(string.Format("The file {0} does not exist!", filePath));
    }
    // END VERY rudimentary error checking

    var numberStrings = Regex.Split(File.ReadAllText(fileInfo.FullName), separator);
    // numberStrings is now an array of strings

    foreach (var numString in numberStrings) {
        if (decimal.TryParse(numString, out var myDecimal)) {
            // Do something w/ number
        } else {
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} is NaN!", numString);
        }
    }

}
```

---

Here's what the code does (written off the top of my head, please don't just C&P it. Test it first):

At first we're defining the regular expression. This matches any character in the range (between the brackets).

Then we're performing very basic error checking:

- If the argument passed is null or empty throw an exception
- If we couldn't parse the argument to a FileInfo object, the path is likely invalid. Throw an exception.
- If the file doesn't exist, throw an exception.

Next we're reading the entire text file in to memory (not on a per-line basis!) and using the regular expression we've defined to split the entire string in to an array of strings.

At last we're looping through our array of strings and parsing each number to a float (that's what you wanted. I personally would use a [double](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double) or [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) for more precision. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0) from Tom Scott.).

If the string doesn't parse to a float, then you can handle the error accordingly. Otherwise do what you need to with the variable myFloat.

---

**EDIT:**
I thought I read you wanting to use floats. My mistake; I changed the datatype to decimal.